# SQL: join (help)

Tags: sql, join

The task is: to join two tables, but not just by columns. Suppose there are tables t1 and t2. In t1, the columns `{id, namet1}`, `t2 - {id, id_t1_with000, namet2}`.

Example

```
t1.id: 
1 
2 
3 
....
```

Example

```
t2.id_t1_with000: 
100 
200 
300 
....
```

Problem: how to connect the tables `t1` and `t2` with `t1.id` and `t2.id_t1_with000`.

I thought that it is possible so:

```
SELECT * FROM t1 JOIN t2 on t1.id = t2.id_t1_with000 [3]
```

How can such a connection be made? How about this google? nothing I could not find.

Comment: In English please or ask in [https://ru.stackoverflow.com/](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @nikita  What DB are you using (mysql, sql server, postgres, oracle)? Если вам это нужно, ответьте на русский, пожалуйста, спросите на http://ru.stackoverflow.com

Comment: Also, is there always two trailing 0's? Like... would "10" be "1000"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could join the tables using a substring.

example:

```
select * from table1 t1
join table2 t2 on substring(cast(t2.id as varchar), 1, len(t2.id)-2) = t1.id
```

With help of the SubString you can simply extract the ID from all those zero's.

"len(t2.id)-2" because you have 2 zero's behind your ID.
This only works if your id is always filled with the same amount of zero's

Comment: This will be enough.